# opposite bounded continuous function

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.

**Prove or Disprove:**

$\forall\ x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\forall\ \epsilon>0\ \exists\ \delta>0$ such that if $\|x-y\|<\epsilon$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\delta$

Comment: **Hint:** bounded sets are relatively compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the position of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ is correct?

If it is, then your statement is correct. Since by given $x$ and $\epsilon$, for any $\|x-y\|<\epsilon$, we have $y$ in a closed ball with radius $\epsilon$ centered at $x$. Since $f$ is continuous, it is bounded by $M$ on this closed ball, hence we have the $\delta=2M$.

Comment: I am 100% sure this is not uniform continuity to check.

Comment: @TrueTopologist Yes. Then since $\delta$ could depend on $x$ and $\epsilon$, basically you are proving the locally boundedness of continuous function on $\mathbb{R^n}$.